# Confidence interval of sum of voting percentages in a poll

Tags: confidence-interval, ratio

I've been looking at wikipedia poll data results for the incoming french presidential election (https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_de_sondages_sur_l%27%C3%A9lection_pr%C3%A9sidentielle_fran%C3%A7aise_de_2022). The page also contains a table for CIs based on the sample size and the score obtained by the candidate.

Now my question is: How would I go about calculating the CI for the sum of several scores.
For exemple, let's say I want to calculate the score for all the left wing (for instance 3 candidates), center (2 candidates), and right wing candidates (3 candidates) and their associated CI, what would be the correct way to do this?

I have the intuition that simply adding the lower-bounds (and upper bounds for the right side) together would be incorrect.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An intuitive approximate approach would be to construct a Wald interval for the proportion of voters who will vote for $k=1,...,K$ different candidates.  If each candidate will receive a proportion $p_k$ of the population vote then we are interested in estimating $\theta=\sum_{i=1}^K p_k$.  A reasonable estimator would be $\hat{\theta}=\sum_{i=1}^K \hat{p}_k$ based on a sample of respondents.  The estimated standard error of this estimator is $\sqrt{\hat{\theta}(1-\hat{\theta})/n}$, where $n$ is the number of respondents in the sample, producing the approximate $100(1-\alpha)\%$ Wald interval

$$ \hat{\theta} \pm z_{1-\alpha/2}\sqrt{\hat{\theta}(1-\hat{\theta})/n}.$$

$z_{1-\alpha/2}$ is the $100(1-\alpha/2)^{th}$ percentile of the standard normal distribution.  For a $95\%$ confidence interval, $z_{1-\alpha/2}=1.96$.

It is important to note that the estimand $\theta$ is the proportion of the total population who would vote for the collection of candidates *if the election were held at the moment the poll was conducted*.  This is to suggest the obvious that $\theta$ may be a function of time.  When the actual election is held the estimand may be different from when the poll was conducted.   Also, I did not incorporate any finite population correction.  If the poll utilizes survey sampling weights these would be incorporated in each $\hat{p}_k$ and normalized to sum to $n$.

Comment: Thank you very much for this.